# Parametrized SQL query in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, sql-server

I have successfully connected to external database and run SQL command to import some data into Excel. However, when I want to change **Query Properties** in **Definition** tab, I can not do anything, since everything there is disabled, including **Parameters** button.

[Snap of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am9Mq.png)

Why is this button unabled?

The end goal is to get parametrized query, where the parameter is in one of the cells. When the value of the cell is changed, query should update.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly have you connected? Isn't your connection file read only?

Comment: Yes , it is read only.

Comment: If its read only then you can't edit it. That's why button is disabled.